# Reduce file size of a print quality image with programmatic text without losing print quality

Tags: c#, image-processing

I need to load an image file, set some text on it, and save it as an image for printing using the code below.

```
private static void A4SizeDpi600() {
    const int dotsPerInch = 600; // define the quality in DPI
    const double widthInInch = 10; // width of the bitmap in INCH
    const double heightInInch = 8; // height of the bitmap in INCH

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(imageFilePath), (int)(widthInInch * dotsPerInch), (int)(heightInInch * dotsPerInch))) //10*600=6000, 8*600=4800
    {
        bitmap.SetResolution(dotsPerInch, dotsPerInch);

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.DrawString("Some text here", new Font("Times New Roman", 0.3f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Inch), Brushes.Black, 1400f, 2100f);
            //more text here

            // Save the bitmap
            bitmap.Save(imageBaseFilePath+ "CertDpi600.png");//file type can be any               
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the resulting image is too big (10MB), the input file is only 600K, which is more than 10 times in size . I want to know if there are ways to reduce the file size without losing printing quality.

The resulting image file type can be any type (pdf, png, bmp, jpeg), as long as it has good printing quality and small file size.

I am open to the input file type too (either any image file type, or pdf), as long as it produces the same requirement above.

Comment: The .Net png library is notoriously unoptimised. Consider looking into third party libraries for saving smaller png files.

Comment: _"The resulting image file type can be any type (pdf, png, bmp, jpeg), as long as it has good printing quality and small file size."_ Um, pdf is not an image format and usually contains jpeg images, jpeg _always_ loses quality on re-save and has a quality percentage argument in its save options, so you choose yourself how large the result will be, and bmp is completely uncompressed by design and thus never small.